# Changing Spring XML configuration to @Configuration

Tags: java, spring

My spring application is already configured via xml stye.I am trying to change it with @Configuration classes.

My app is used another project as maven library.I have a service, annotated with @Named and this service is used by another service in the library.

```
@Named("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl extends AbstractServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Inject
private UserService userService;

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    return userService.getByUserName(username);
 }
}



@Named("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl extends BaseDaoServiceImpl<User, UserDao> implements UserService {

@Inject
private AuthorityService authorityService;

@Inject
private UserAuthorityService userAuthorityService;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public User getByUserName(String username) {

    return dao.getByUserName(username);
}

@Override
public List<User> getUserWithHasAuthority(String authorityName) {
    return dao.getUserWithHasAuthority(authorityName);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public User insert(User user) {

    user.setEnabled(true);
    super.insert(user);

    Authority authority = authorityService.getByName("ROLE_USER");

    UserAuthority userAuthority = new UserAuthority();
    userAuthority.setAuthority(authority);
    userAuthority.setUser(user);
    userAuthorityService.insert(userAuthority);

    return user;
 }
}
```

On my new @Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mylibrary","com.myapp"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ServiceTestConfiguration {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }

}
```

and this is my test method:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "admin");
    authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
}
```

it gives null pointer exception on userService property that exist in userDetailsService.Both of them @Named.

Thnx for your help

Test classes :

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ServiceTestConfiguration.class, DataSourceConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class})
@Transactional
public class AbstractTest {
}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest extends AbstractTest {

@Inject
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Test
public void test() {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "admin");
    authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
 }
}
```

Comment: can you share the test class configuration?

Comment: i edited question

Comment: I don't see any of wrong on your configuration or I mean I don't any of very bed I just suggest a better organization of class in your test but it isn't a vital tinks probably the error is in your spring security cnfiguration

Comment: Yes u are right.I had a mistake on Security configuration.Instead of injecting UserDetailsService, i put it on AuthenticationManagerBuilder with new Constr. :) thnks

Comment: happy to have helped